# Matlab array notation

Tags: python, matlab

What does this mean in matlab code:

```
array1(array2)
```

and also

```
sum(array1(array2)).^2
```

In python, is it something similar to:

```
array1[array2]
sum((array1[array2])**2)
```

Comment: Note that while python uses indices starting from 0, matlab starts from 1 (probably due to the fortran legacy).

Answer (score 2):

`array1(array2)` will return the values of `array1` indexed by `array2`

Example:

```
array1=[2 4 6 8];
array2=[2 4]
array1(array2)
>> [4 8]
```

Thus, `sum(array1(array2)).^2` will sum the result of the indexing and then square it. In our example, `(4+8).^2`

Answer (score 1):

Indexing in matlab is `()` in python `[]`. If you have numpy arrays, this is the same:

```
array1[array2]
```

and

```
array1[array2].sum() ** 2
```